# windows batch file exits when running mercurial commands

Tags: windows, git, mercurial, batch-file, cmd

For daily backup of my mercurial repositories on Windows XP I used a simple batch file `hg_backup.bat` which just did some directory changes and mercurial calls with a `pause` command in the end like this:

```
@Z:
@cd \hg_backup\drawings
hg pull -v
@cd \hg_backup\src\scripts
hg pull -v
@cd \hg_backup\eagle4\lbr
hg pull -v
@pause
```

This worked fine with mercurial up to 1.7 (installed with TortoiseHg). However since mercurial 1.8 it starts the very first mercurial command and then exits abruptly without reaching the following commands or even the end of the script. The command window just disappears.

I had the same problem some time before, when I tried the same thing with git, but didn't investigate further, because I use git for one repository only. It seems to me, there's some return code of the hg command line call involved which causes the script to end instead of executing the other command but I couldn't verify this yet.

Has anyone an idea why this happens or maybe even how to fix it?

Comment: launch a command terminal and run the batch file in it, you should have some error message.

Comment: No, there are no error messages at all, when doing it this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your `hg` is a `hg.bat` or `hg.cmd`, use **`call hg`** and see if it starts working.

The `command.com` shell executes batch files *replacing* the old script (to save memory), and requires using `call` to start a batch script and continue execution later. This behavior remains in Windows `cmd.exe` for compatibility.

Comment: You're right, the hg called is in fact `hg.cmd` and using `call` in front of each invocation of hg in my batch file solves the problem. Thanks. :-)

Comment: I wonder what is behind the decision to expose the .cmd file as part of the installed tools, it wasn't done in an older version and upgrading broke my entire build server due to this.

Comment: @Lasse: In some cases, to avoid putting the real directory in `%PATH%` (since it also affects DLL search, and many cross-platform software uses a lot of libraries; a few examples are GTK+ using programs). In other cases, to prepare the runtime environment; could be an attempt to automagically find the right `python.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, but the solution provided by @grawity didn't work for me (and I have no idea why).

The solution in my case was to replace `call` with `cmd /C`, like so:

```
cmd /C hg sum
cmd /C hg stat
```

Comment: Probably because he was referring to bat/cmd files only. IIRC call doesn't work on anything else. Cmd-C does.